# How convert SVG to JPEG in java

Tags: java, svg, jpeg, batik

I have a **MulipartFile** object which caries an SVG image. I want to convert that into **JPEG format**. How can I achieve this ? I tried the following, But getting an Enclosed Exception as the system cannot find the file specified.

```
        JPEGTranscoder t = new JPEGTranscoder();

        File f = new File("temp.svg");
        multipartfile.transferTo(f);
        // Create a JPEG transcoder

        // Set the transcoding hints.
        t.addTranscodingHint(JPEGTranscoder.KEY_QUALITY,
                   new Float(.8));

        // Create the transcoder input.
        String svgURI = f.toURL().toString();
        TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(svgURI);

        // Create the transcoder output.
        OutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream("out.jpg");
        TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(ostream);

        // Save the image.
        t.transcode(input, output);

        // Flush and close the stream.
        ostream.flush();
        ostream.close();
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? One of the first results in an internet search engine for `batik convert svg to jpeg` is https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using batik 1.8, as following steps are working with batik 1.7 but fail with 1.8.

1. download the binary distribution version 1.7 from one of the [batik download mirrors](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/xmlgraphics/batik)
2. extract the archive (will create directory `./batik-1.7.1/`
3. save the example `SaveAsJPEG.java` from [batik transcoder example](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/transcoder.html)
4. compile it
   `javac -cp batik-1.7.1/batik.jar SaveAsJPEG.java`
5. run it
   `java -cp batik.jar:. SaveAsJPEG foobar.svg`

This will create an `out.jpg`.

Using the same steps for version 1.8 lead into

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException: null
Enclosed Exception:
null
     at org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.ImageTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
     at SaveAsJPEG.main(SaveAsJPEG.java:27)
```

Comment: which java version you are using ??